# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: kotlin

C:/Users/LENOVO/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/33fa47401fa8ac91195ccfa117fbdede/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I've solved it as follow:

Add it in build.gradle (module)

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
```

Add it in build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.3'
    }
}
plugins {
    [...]
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem. But I still don't know the logic behind the same. :(