# Flutter Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

In flutter getting `** Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.**`

After formatting the system installed Android Studio - Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Kotlin version - 212-1.6.10-release-923-AS5457.46

Flutter version 3.7.3 and Dart version 2.19.2

Have tried

- Invalidating cache
- Cleaning gradle files
- In Android Studio, you can go to Build -> Clean Project
- flutter clean, flutter pub get
- Have also formatted the OS from the system and reinstalled

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 12.6.6 21G646 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Detailed Step by step answer to resolve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255068/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately this does not help @KenWhite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We faced the same issue and our project was at a stand still for a whole week,

**RCA:**

The issue was caused because of the **^** we add in front of the flutter package versions. Due to which the pubspec.lock got modified with a latest version of the packages.

**Solution:**

We removed the **^** from the versions and followed below steps

1. flutter pub cache clean
2. delete pubspec.lock
3. flutter pub get

this resulted in the pubspec.lock being generated again with the exact versions of the packages mentioned in the pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Change `kotlin` version to 1.6.0 or above in `android/build.gradle`.

kotlin-version https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' // update kotlin version
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: The issue has been resolved by replacing current pubspec.lock file with previous pubspec.lock file

Comment: Great :). I also faced this error, updating kotlin version works for me.